# Greatest Common Divisors in integral domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Assume that $R$ is an integral domain. I want to prove that every finite subset $B$ has a greatest common divisor if and only if $B$ has a least common multiple. (As the (helpful) comment below shows, this is not immediately obvious.) I tried to use mathematical induction on the number of elements in $B$. If $B$ has 2 elements, say $b_1$, and $b_2$ then the identity $${\rm gcd}(b_1, b_2){\rm lcm}(b_1, b_2)={b_1}{b_2}$$ helps. The above identity can be proved using elementary divisibility arguments, and my checking it through seems to show that holds in an arbitrary integral domain. But even if $B$ has $3$ elements, the identity linking the product to the greatest common divisor, and least common multiple becomes complicated. Not sure how to set up the induction step. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> but I am trying to answer the question in a general integral domain

Not possible, since [there are examples of domains that don't admit GCDs](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=8&L=123). The special ones that do are called [gcd domains](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain) and that is indeed equivalent to having lcms.

> If two elements in an integral domain are coprime, can one write 1 as an R
>   -linear combination of these elements?

No, for example, try to write $1$ as a combination of $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb Z[x,y]$.

> I tried to prove this by induction on the number of elements in B

I think all you need induction for, maybe, is to reassure yourself that the gcd condition you have works for all such $B$ iff it works for all pairs of elements. The same goes for lcms, then you can work with the much simpler pairwise conditions.

> If the gcd of any subset B in an integral domain R can be written as a finite linear combination of the elements in B (with R coefficients), then R must be a PID. No idea how to prove this!

Neither do I, because this is also *not true.* A [Bézout domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout_domain) is a GCD domain in which you can write GCDs as a linear combination, but Bezout domains [are not PIDs in general](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=68l&L=65l).

Comment: If the gcd of any subset B in an integral domain R can be written as a finite linear combination of the elements in B (with R coefficients), then R must be a PID. No idea how to prove this!

Comment: @student I've added to my solution to address your comment. I don't know where you're getting these "facts" but my advice is to vet them more carefully in the future. Otherwise you'll lose a lot of time attempting to prove false statements.

Comment: This is an exercise in the textbook "A Course in Galois Theory" by D.J. H. Garling. Exercise 3.21, page 31. I seem to have figured it out. As far as I can make out, we consider any non-zero ideal J (say), and prove that the greatest common divisor d (say) generates J. One has to prove the set inclusions both ways and it seems straight-forward.

Comment: rschweib-your hint proved very helpful. I solved the question that I raised. I will post my solution when I have time. The question is also from the same textbook: A Course in Galois Theory by D.J.H. Garling. It is Exercise 3.19, page 30.

Comment: Your comment about Bezout domains makes sense. I think the hypothesis in the exercise in Garling's book is that R is a Bezout domain. He does not use this terminology, but to prove a very basic statement like the one in that exercise, I guess it is safe to omit the terminology.

Comment: rschweib.  I thought hard about your comments-and was a little worried that the book may be wrong! But I think I understand now. The question I posted above does not claim that any integral domain admits a gcd. It merely asks you to prove that if every finite subset admits a gcd, then it should admit an lcm, and vice-versa. In Exercise 3.21, the hypothesis seems to be that one is working in a Bezout domain : If J is a non-zero ideal, and d = gcd(J), since d is in J (d) must be a subset of J. Conversely since d = gcd(J), d must divide every element of J and so J must be contained in (d).

Answer (score 0):

We argue by mathematical induction. If $B$ is a singleton $\{b\}$, then $b$ is both its own greatest common divisor, and its own least common multiple. So the existence  of $b$ ensures that the existence of the gcd is equivalent to the existence of the lcm. If $n=2$, and $B$ is an arbitrary subset $B=\{b_1, b_2\}$, then the identity $${\rm gcd}(b_1, b_2){\rm lcm}(b_1, b_2) = {b_1}{b_2}$$ proves that the existence of the gcd is equivalent to the existence of the lcm.
To treat the case with more than two elements, I first established the following identities by mathematical induction $${d_n}:={\rm gcd}(b_1,\cdots ,b_n) = {\rm gcd}({\rm gcd}(b_1,\cdots ,b_{n-1}), b_n),$$ and $${m_n}:={\rm lcm}(b_1,\cdots ,b_n) = {\rm lcm}({\rm lcm}(b_1,\cdots ,b_{n-1}), b_n).$$
Then assume (as our induction hypothesis) that the existence of the gcd is equivalent to the existence the lcm for any subset consisting of $k$ elements for any $2\leq k\leq n$, and assume that $B$ is an arbitrary subset of $R$ consisting of $n+1$ elements. If $d_{n+1}$ exists, since $$d_{n+1}={\rm gcd}(d_n,b_{n+1}),$$ the existence of $d_n$ implies the existence of $m_n$, (by our induction hypothesis), and by the result for $n =2$, we conclude that $${\rm lcm}(m_n, b_{n+1}) = {\rm lcm}(b_1,\cdots ,b_{n+1})=m_{n+1}$$ must exist. The converse implication is proved with a very similar argument, and the assertion follows by mathematical induction.